# Overriding Drawables in Android

Tags: android, xml, drawable, exoplayer

I stumbled upon the following information in the ExoPlayer documentation for [PlayerNotificationManager](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerNotificationManager.html)

> The drawables used by PlayerNotificationManager can be overridden by drawables with the same names defined in your application.

Overriding drawables - I have no idea how to do that:

1. Should I create my own drawables with the exact names specified in the documentation - for example `exo_notification_rewind.xml` ?
2. Can I create a XML mapping file - like `/res/values/drawables.xml`?

Content of `drawables.xml` would be:

```
<resources>
  <drawable name="exo_notification_fastforward">@drawable/my_custom_fastforward_icon</drawable>
  <drawable name="exo_notification_rewind">@drawable/my_custom_rewind_icon</drawable>
</resources>
```

I tried both approaches. I cannot rule out an Android Studio caching problem, but both approaches did not work in my project.

So if anyone knows the canonical way to Overriding Drawables... That would be super-great.

Comment: Yeah you should create a file with same name inside drawable folder . Also check for Version in Exo player because you will have to override each version . there may be different files for  `V-21` or `V-23` .

Comment: This solution somehow did not work in my project.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was to create a `values.xml` files in `/res/values/` with this content.

```
<resources>
    <drawable name="exo_notification_fastforward">@drawable/my_custom_fastforward_icon</drawable>
    <drawable name="exo_notification_rewind">@drawable/my_custom_rewind_icon</drawable>
</resources>
```

I am not sure, why the other solutions laid out above did not work for me.